# Execute code before screen rotation

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I want to execute some code before process screen rotation.
But I don't want to override `onConfigurationChanged` method because I want to use system to perform rotation.

I have to use a "clean way" to perform that.

I'm a clear ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you override the method but still call `super.onConfigurationChanged(conf)` you're essentially *extending* it's functionality, meaning you can execute your code and still get the rotation or whatever the method normally does.

That's as clean as it gets

Comment: With `onConfigurationChanged`, `onCreateView()` is not called when rotation append. So my view is not re-drawn.